# Making a total number count appear to increase

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have a class counting system that displays the number of classes and displays them in a `span` element. Below is the code:

```
$.get('other.html', function(data) {
$('#total').html($('.doc', data).length);
});
```

This works perfectly, however I'd like a way to have the numbers increasing one by one since the span element contains 0 when the page loads. Here's an [example (the numbers increasing on here).](http://www.worldometers.info/)

For this I have tried `setTimeout` and despite this not working anyway, I released it would simply delay the function and then display the end number. I have heard of `periodical` or something similar being used but could not find this in the example source code.

I am really sorry for more poor phrasing. If you have no idea what I mean then just ask and I'll try rephrase or find a better example.

Comment: periodical is `setInterval()` in Javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

Answer (score 0):

The key is the function which increases the number should set a setTimeout to call itself, before termination. This way it will always be called again. If you want the option to stop the incrementing, you can add a global variable, and the function will only set a new timeout when that variable is true.

Example:

```
var doIncrement = true;
var numberToIncrement = 0;

function increment {
    numberToIncrement++;
    $('#mySpan').text(numberToIncrement);
    if (doIncrement) {
        setTimeout(increment, 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `setInterval` function that allows you to run code at some time intervals. `clearInterval` allows to stop the task.

http://jsfiddle.net/d52Pw/

```
var $totalEl = $('#total');

$.get('other.html', function(data) {
    var len = $('.doc', data).length,
        count = 0,
        int = setInterval(function () {
            if (++count === len) {
               //when we reach len, we stop the task
               clearInterval(int);
            }

            $totalEl.html(count);
        }, 500); //run every 1/2 sec
});
```

Comment: Works well on the fiddle, but not on my site. i'll try a few things and edit if i can fix. +1 for now.

Comment: @LiamB Note that I reference `$totalEl` here, did you define that variable?